# Install Package for perl in windows

Tags: perl, cgi, movabletype

I wanted to install Movable Type in my server , I have installed Perl version: v5.16.3 in my own server and add handler mapping for it .
perl(cgi files) runs good but before of installing mt I should have installed two package for mt :

```
1 - DBD::mysql 
2- DBD::SQLite2
```

i have installed first on but not succesfull  to install intsalling `DBD::SQLite2` on Perl with running `ppm install DBD-SQLite2` i get not found error.

[Address of Mt Check file on server](http://fa.nnawheel.com/mt/mt-check.cgi)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install DBD:SQLite2.

See the system requirements at:
http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/system-requirements.html

The support for 'DBD::SQLite2' is deprecated in movable type v5.x and you would like to install v5.2.3 which is the latest version and the one supported and further developed.

Thanks,
Mihai

Comment: i have movable type v4 , so i need to install this package